# PAM - find the control flag (required, sufficient)

Tags: c, pam

I'm patching an OTP module ([yubico_pam](https://github.com/Yubico/yubico-pam)) and I'm trying to access the **control-flag** selected by the administrator (e.g. **required, sufficient**, etc).

Any idea? Is this feasible at all (without parsing the file)?

Comment: The PAM stack is supposed to interpet that. AFAIK, there is no API to inquire that bit of information. Maybe we can get around the necessity to know that. What are you trying to do?

Comment: That's what I figured. I really need this since the authentication logic change depending on this. What I'll do is add a new option and tell in the documentation that they should only use this option when using require control flag (otherwise, it's a security risk).

Comment: I'm implementing an opt-out feature. Take a look at https://code.google.com/p/yubico-pam/issues/detail?id=34

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no way to query this information within the API. We have to avoid the need of knowing this value or specifically instruct the user on what control-flag he should use.